# getText().toString() adds some numbers before what is typed

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext

I have instanced the variable:

```
  editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
```

Then on click of a button I want to put it in a database:

```
//CHECK FORM
if (editname.getText().toString().matches("")){
...toast...
return;
}
check_value=editname.getText().toString();
//DATABASE
if (myDB.insertData(editname.getText().toString()){//Insert data
Toast.makeText(..., R.string.data_inserted + check_value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Once it is on the database I send it to a fragment after a click on a button:

```
Fragment newFragment = new PreviewFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


String get_id = Integer.toString(myDB.getId(check_value)); //Get  ID //java.lang.NullPointerException
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("id", get_id);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, newFragment);
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.commit();
```

On the implementation of the fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    String id;

    try {
        id = getArguments().getString("id");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return view;
    }


    Cursor res = myDB.getValues(id);
    }
```

And in that line I see java.lang.NullPointerException

Once I added the check_value I could see that the text I got was not what I introduced in the box but this:

```
2131099688(Followed by the text I introduced)
```

Anyone knows the reason for this? I already removed the app and cleaned the project but I still get the same.

Comment: "And in that line I see java.lang.NullPointerException" which line exactly ?

Comment: I already got it solved thanks, It was due to a wrong method call in my database query,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the result of what you put in your toast.

```
Toast.makeText(..., R.string.data_inserted + check_value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The number before `check_value` is the id of the string `data_inserted`.

Try to `getString(R.string.data_inserted)` instead of the id.

Comment: Thank you, that was It, but my problem with the null exception is still there. I thought the reason was that the variable took a different name than what I had typed but it seems like it must be another thing.